# Prove cohomologous using the infinitesimal calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I was reading Huybrechts complex geometry book. In Lemma 4.4.6 proving the $$[P(F_\nabla)]  = [P(F_{\tilde{\nabla}})]$$ for different connection. Uising an infinitesimal calculation method.

The proof goes as follows:

Lemma 4.4.6 If $\nabla$ and $\nabla^{\prime}$ are two connections on the same bundle $E$, then $\left[\tilde{P}\left(F_{\nabla}\right)\right]=\left[\tilde{P}\left(F_{\nabla^{\prime}}\right)\right]$(where $P$ is some invariant polynomial.)

---

The space of all connections is an affine space over $\mathcal{A}^1(M, \operatorname{End}(E))$, i.e. if $\nabla$ is given, then any other connection is of the form $\nabla^{\prime}=\nabla+A$ for some $A \in \mathcal{A}^1(\operatorname{End}(E))$ (see Corollary 4.2.4). Thus, it suffices to show that the induced map
$$
\mathcal{A}^1(M, \operatorname{End}(E)) \longrightarrow H^{2 k}(M, \mathbb{C})
$$
is constant. We use that $F_{\nabla+A}=F_{\nabla}+A \wedge A+\nabla(A)$.
The assertion can be proven by an infinitesimal calculation, i.e. in the following calculation we only consider terms of order at most one in $t$ :
$$
\tilde{P}\left(F_{\nabla+t A}\right)=\tilde{P}\left(F_{\nabla}\right)+k t P\left(F_{\nabla}, \ldots, F_{\nabla}, \nabla(A)\right) .
$$
Now the assertion follows from Lemma $4.4 .4$ and the Bianchi identity:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(F_{\nabla}, \ldots, F_{\nabla}, \nabla(A)\right)=& d P\left(F_{\nabla}, \ldots, F_{\nabla}, A\right)-P\left(\nabla\left(F_{\nabla}\right), F_{\nabla}, \ldots, F_{\nabla}, A\right)-\ldots \\
&-P\left(F_{\nabla}, \ldots, F_{\nabla}, \nabla\left(F_{\nabla}\right), A\right) \\
=& d P\left(F_{\nabla}, \ldots, F_{\nabla}, A\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I haven't learned this method to prove cohomologous before. why only needs to consider the first order terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not so hard, the key point is the **fundamental theorem of calculus.**

if $\omega_t$ is a smooth path of differential form. and the following differential equation $$\frac{d}{dt}\omega_t = d\eta_t$$ then $$\omega_1 - \omega_0 =\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}\omega_t dt = \int_0^1 d\eta_t dt = d \int_0^1 \eta_t dt$$

Therefore we see it's cohomologous.

---

For the proof above

$$k  P\left(F_{\nabla}, \ldots, F_{\nabla}, \nabla(A)\right) .
$$
Is the first order derivative of $\omega_t$ w.r.t $\ t$.